# While passing an json array from one view controller to another,I'm getting 'nil' value in second view controller array

Tags: uitableview, swift3, segue, xcode8

Sorry for repeating this question but i'm not sure what gone wrong in my code can anyone help me to clear that error.

Below I have attached my code snippets for more clarification.

[this is my first viewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oAqzc.png)

In my firstViewController Im having a variable which stores the son array and I'm passing that to a variable in secondViewController.
Below is secondViewControllers Snippet.

[SecondViewController](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GtDKm.png)

In my secondViewController my Variable value becomes bill.
while I'm passing its having an array of value 
When I access that variable within my secondViewController it shows a bill value.

Comment: please give more info

Comment: I have posted the code,what else you need?,can you specify.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the return and else portion from uour code,
When checking the StationDetails.isEmpty.

It is also better to embed your code into stackOverflow than
To use an external links.